# Meaning of ./ in the below HTML code

Tags: html, forms, uri

**Hi Friends...**

**What will happen when submit button is clicked...**

`<form name="form" action="./" method="post">`

**What action will be done for ./
Kindly comment the relevant answers...
Thanks in Advance**

Comment: you shouldn't be poiting to a path in a form, instead you should be pointing to a URI

Comment: default server action will happen for this path.

Comment: Use it and find out. That would be faster than asking on here.

Comment: Wow what an answer Mr.Justin Wood

Comment: Hello Hal9000 if you don't mind can you give me a  brief description about default server action?

Comment: Do some research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It will ask the server for the default file in the current directory. Usually that is `index.html`, `index.htm`, `index.php`, ...

But depending on the setup / configuration of the server (including redirects), it could take you to http://www.monkeybusiness.tv/spamalot.asp?user=me&password=secret

There is no way of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of # as a URL reference (whether as `action` or `formaction` attribute value or otherwise) is a reference to the start of the current base document. The base document is the current document, unless a `<base href=...>` tag has been set.

What happens depends on the situation. Typically, the browser requests for the page again with a query part in the URL (and the page is loaded again, which may imply that client-side scripts are run), but if the same query had been used earlier, the browser probably uses its cache. Moreover, as the start of the document is referred to, focus on any form element is lost and the page may scroll backwards.

So although `#` is fairly common in some coding styles, it is reliable; its purpose is better achieved using client-side event handlers.

The `formaction` attribute has a meaning only for submit buttons. A text input element does not constitute a submit button, even though it may trigger form submission, so here the attribute is ignored.